# there is a gab in the donut icing however i increased the geometry and also the thickness with the solidfy and sub devesion modifires

Tags: modeling, geometry

[image: i applied a subdivision modifire as well as solidify but when i use the proportion editing tool to move the vertices downward a gab was caused]

i applied a subdivision modifier as well as solidify but when i used the proportion editing tool to move the vertices downward a gap was caused, and I tried to increase the thickness and that did really solve the problem but with a high amount of thickness it doesn't looks like an icing

Comment: Hello maybe use the snap option to stick the vertices to the surface of the donut? If it doesn't work please share the file

Comment: @moonboots

acutally it think you just said what is inside me : the guy in the tutorial  when he moves the vertices i was moving on the surface of the donut but mine gone underneath it

so how could i move them on the surface and prevent them from moving down?

note: i did use the snapping tool and use the option "face project" but this is the result the camed

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots 
okay i did share it along with the URL of my question, thanks in advance man❤️

Comment: I can't see the link, you need to copy paste it in your question

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4ZmQmrdD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4ZmQmrdD/)

this one?

@moonboots

Comment: @moonboots
i am sorry it may sound impulsive, but can we chat over discord or something?
i mean it will be a lot easier this way, or if you know a discord blender community please share the link, thanks.

Comment: sure please join https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Comment: @moonboots

thanks so much i joined it

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>G</kbd> and your vertex will stick to the surface of the donut, you can also choose *Snap Individual Elements To > Face Project* in the *Snap With* panel, and if you select several vertices it will snap them individually to the surface:

[image]